# Perl: Parse string as shell

Tags: perl, quotes

I would like to dequote and split a string the same way Bash does (excluding ` and $). Given the string:

```
'"'"'\""'"'  foo\ bar\"   '\" '\ quux
```

I would like an array containing:

```
@a = (q("'""), 'foo bar"', '\"  quux');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
use Text::ParseWords ();
my @list = Text::ParseWords::shellwords($string);
```

Comment: Why `require` and not `use`?

Comment: Because there is no reason to import any subroutines.  `use Module;` = `BEGIN { require Module; Module->import( LIST ); }`, see perldoc http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use.html

Comment: One might argue that importing subroutines is why you use a module in the first place. If you do not want to import anything you can do `use Text::ParseWords ()`.

Comment: ya :), I agree with you.  But does it really need to be done in compile time?  `Getopt::Long::GetoptionsFromString` uses `require` too.  http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/JV/Getopt-Long-2.42/lib/Getopt/Long.pm

Comment: If the `require` is in an `if` statement, it may never be run. A `use` in an `if` statement will always be run. I need it in an `if` statement.

Comment: @ernix: When the rest of the world is using `use`, you need a good reason to buck the trend. *"[Because it doesn't] really need to be done in compile time"* isn't a good reason: it is best to move as much as possible to compile time. The `GetOptionsFromString` subroutine uses `require` because it is a waste to load `Text::ParseWords` for the entire module when it is used only for this specialised subroutine.

Comment: I would rather stick to the coding style in the project, not the rest of the world.  I wish using `use Text::ParseWords ();` if there were bunch of `use` statements on the top of the code.  But the code obviously is partial and I have no idea what is in the BEGIN block.  It might be in the same situation with `Getopt::Long`. That's why I mentioned about compile time.

Comment: Re "Because there is no reason to import any subroutines." So use `use Text::ParseWords ();`

Comment: hmm OK, I follow the common way.